# Who would you like to hear at our Scalability Conference?

Tags: discussion

We are currently working on getting speakers for our [Scalability Conference](http://scalability.serverfault.com/) that will be in San Francisco on October 14th.

The theme for the conference is talks on scalable operations and system administration. The goal is to cover ideas, tools, and techniques that apply to this aspect of scalability that will be useful for system administrators, even those who have smaller environments.

If you are interested in speaking yourself, you can fill out our [call for speakers submission form](http://devdays.squarespace.com/cfp/).

Are there any speakers that anyone from our community would recommend or like to hear? If you know some people well enough to make introductions, that would also be appreciated.

Comment: Just a note to contributors in this thread: One person per post, please. That way upvotes are given to one potential speaker and not confused by a gaggle of potential speakers in one post.

Comment: Does anyone know anyone from somewhere like Facebook that started with a small system and ended up having to hyper-scale it? I've read a bit lately how they've been stung by decisions that were good for a startup, bad for a mega-giant, but you never know how much of it is real or hyped.

Comment: Also, although it's not directly related to scalability, I'm seeing so much mis-information about IPv6, it would be great to have someone teach the fundamentals of IPv6. Man I wish I could go to this conference.

Comment: What joker voted to close this as too localized? O_o

Comment: @WesleyDavid, that would be me. The question is about a conference in a single city. How much more localised can it get?

Comment: To redressing John's concern, it would be ultra spectacular if some (or even all) of the presentations could be put up on the scalability.SF site. I know there are *a lot* of people who wish they could go, but it just isn't feasible.

Comment: @John Okay, fair enough. But I thought that since it was sponsored by the site as a whole it would be a body of information that would be shared with and benefit the entire group. Even though I likely won't be able to go there, I'll probably benefit from the talks.

Comment: This is one of those times that I wish I didn't work in mainly small business networking. I regularly scale my Server Fault rep, but that's about it...

Answer (score 10):

Chopper3 on vmware esx[i]/vsphere scalability & storage area networks

Comment: That would be totally awesome.

Comment: I used to think I knew what I was talking about with vsphere and SANs. Turns out I know almost nothing compared to people like chopper3.

Comment: It's amazing the amount of knowledge that is encompassed by the people that frequent the site.  I wish I was a little better at absorbing it all.

Answer (score 2):

Dr. Evan Cooke, CTO of Twilio

I'm biased because I also work at Twilio, but he's very, very smart. I've learned a lot from working together.

Answer (score 1):

John Allspaw seems to be a major go-to-guy for scaling web things.

Answer (score 1):

Theo Schlossnagle is another guy that seems to be a master of large systems scaling.

Answer (score 1):

From teh twitters:

Brian Aker

.... answer length fail